# GROUP BY with DECODE in Oracle SQL (ORA-00979)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum, decode

I just read a lot of resolved question regarding my issue on stackoverflow and other websites but I still didn't get it. I can't execute my attached code and I get "ORA-00979" error but I don't get why. I read that I don't have to list DECODE or COUNT clauses in my GROUP BY order. I still get the error. Does anyone know why?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    company.company_id,   
    company.companyname_1,   
    customer.customer_id,   
    customer.customername_1,
    DECODE(receipt.table_name, 'PAYMENT', SUM(COUNT(receipt.receipt_id))) as inpayment
FROM 
            company
    JOIN customer ON company.company_id = customer.company_id
    JOIN debtor ON customer.customer_id = debtor.customer_id
    JOIN debtortrunk ON debtor.debtor_id = debtortrunk.debtor_id 
    JOIN receipt ON debtor.customer_id = receipt.customer_id AND debtor.deb_id = receipt.deb_id
WHERE
    receipt.created >= '24.01.2018' AND
    receipt.created <= '28.01.2018'
GROUP BY
    company.company_id,   
    company.companyname_1,   
    customer.customer_id,   
    customer.customername_1
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? The aggregation inside the DECODE looks wrong to me, particularly SUM and COUNT together: maybe you need to DECODE first (i.e. as the innermost clause) and then aggregate the result of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want with a `LEFT JOIN` and no conditional logic in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT co.company_id, co.companyname_1,   
       cu.customer_id, cu.customername_1,
       COUNT(r.receipt_id) as inpayment
FROM company co JOIN
     customer cu
     ON co.company_id = cu.company_id JOIN
     debtor d
     ON cu.customer_id = d.customer_id JOIN
     debtortrunk dt
     ON d.debtor_id = dt.debtor_id LEFT JOIN
     receipt r
     ON d.customer_id = r.customer_id AND
        d.deb_id = r.deb_id AND
        r.table_name = 'PAYMENT'
WHERE r.created >= DATE '2018-01-24' AND
      r.created <= DATE '2018-01-28'
GROUP BY co.company_id, co.companyname_1,   
         cu.customer_id, cu.customername_1;
```

Notes:

- You probably do not need the `debtortrunk` table.  It does not appear to be used in the query.
- Use table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.
- Use `DATE` to introduce date constants.  That way, the literal value has the right type.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you very much dude!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use aggregate function contain another aggregate function.

If I understand correctly you can try to use condition aggregate function to make it.

```
SELECT  
    company.company_id,   
    company.companyname_1,   
    customer.customer_id,   
    customer.customername_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN receipt.table_name = 'PAYMENT' AND receipt.receipt_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as inpayment
FROM 
            company
    JOIN customer ON company.company_id = customer.company_id
    JOIN debtor ON customer.customer_id = debtor.customer_id
    JOIN debtortrunk ON debtor.debtor_id = debtortrunk.debtor_id 
    JOIN receipt ON debtor.customer_id = receipt.customer_id AND debtor.deb_id = receipt.deb_id
WHERE
    receipt.created >= '24.01.2018' AND
    receipt.created <= '28.01.2018'
GROUP BY
    company.company_id,   
    company.companyname_1,   
    customer.customer_id,   
    customer.customername_1
```

if you use an aggregate function with `group by`, the distinct make no sense so it might be removed.

Answer (score 0):

`ORA-00979: not a group by expression` means that within your SELECT there is some expression which is not included as a group expression nor involved into an aggregation function. In this case, it is surely the `receipt.table_name` reference.

Most immediate solution would be to include that explicitly as an aggregation field:

```
GROUP BY
company.company_id,   
company.companyname_1,   
customer.customer_id,   
customer.customername_1,
receipt.table_name
```